# OpenGL es glDrawTexfOES() 2D texture not rendering

Tags: java, android, opengl-es

First of all I know this is a duplicated question and I check out another questions but didn't helped! I'm trying to convert my android game from canvas system to the GL10. After lots of googling I decided to do that for performans. Anyway I tryed to build a class that loads and draws textures. The problem is textures showing up whole black over my blue screen.
I'm not sure If I can draw texture without creating any mesh or something like that but this is what I'm trying to do. I'm only trying to draw 2D texture on their own sizes so I think no mesh needed. Here are my codes:

> onSurfaceCreated

```
    @Override
    public void onSurfaceCreated(GL10 gl, EGLConfig config) {
        gl.glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.2f);
        gl.glClearDepthf(1.0f);
        gl.glViewport(0, 0, 800,  480);

        gl.glShadeModel(GL10.GL_SMOOTH);
        gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_DEPTH_TEST);
        gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D);
        gl.glDepthFunc(GL10.GL_LEQUAL);
        gl.glMatrixMode(GL10.GL_PROJECTION);
        gl.glHint(GL10.GL_PERSPECTIVE_CORRECTION_HINT, GL10.GL_NICEST);
        //gl.glHint(GL10.GL_PERSPECTIVE_CORRECTION_HINT, GL10.GL_FASTEST);
        gl.glLoadIdentity();
        // This is the class where I load and draw my textures.
        textureStorage = new TextureStorage(gl);
        //I'm loading a texture.      **CODE A TEXTURE LOADER**
        bgNightID  = textureStorage.Load(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(),R.drawable.bg_game));
        //This is where I load my units variables. Nothing to do with it.
        RenderingFunctions.InitUnits(this);
    }
```

> onDrawFrame

```
@Override
public void onDrawFrame(GL10 gl) {
    gl.glClear(GL10.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL10.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    gl.glLoadIdentity();
    //gl.glTranslatef(0, 0, -4);
        **CODE B DRAWING**
        // bgNightID is the ID of texture was loaded.
        textureStorage.DrawTexture(bgNightID, 50,50,0,(short)4000,(short)638);
        // Drawing background right here which is shows up black. 
}
```

> CODE A  TEXTURE LOADER

```
public int glLoad( Bitmap bitmap ){
    if ( gl == null ){
        Log.e(TAG, "Failed to load resource.  Context/GL is NULL");return -1;
    }
    int textureName = -1;
    gl.glGenTextures(1, TexIDStorage, 0);
    textureName = TexIDStorage[0];

    Log.d(TAG, "Generated texture: " + textureName);
    gl.glBindTexture(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureName);

    gl.glTexParameterf(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL10.GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL10.GL_LINEAR);
    gl.glTexParameterf(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL10.GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL10.GL_LINEAR);
    //gl.glTexParameterf(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL10.GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL10.GL_NEAREST);
    gl.glTexParameterf(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL10.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL10.GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    gl.glTexParameterf(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL10.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL10.GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    gl.glTexEnvf(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GL10.GL_TEXTURE_ENV_MODE, GL10.GL_REPLACE);

    GLUtils.texImage2D(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, bitmap, 0);

    int error = gl.glGetError();
    if (error != GL10.GL_NO_ERROR){ 
        Log.e(TAG, "GL Texture Load Error: " + error);
    }else
        Log.d(TAG, "Loaded texture: " + textureName);
    return textureName;
}
```

> CODE B DRAWING

```
public void DrawTexture(int TexutreID, float X, float Y, float Z, short Width, short Height){
    gl.glClear(GL10.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL10.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    //gl.glColor4f(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 0.5f);
    gl.glBindTexture(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, TexIDStorage[TexutreID]);
    ((GL11Ext) gl).glDrawTexfOES(X, Y, Z, Width, Height);
}
```

I'm totaly new to GL10 and can't figure out what is the problem and what is it I'm missing. So if anyone can help me that would be great. Thank you for givim time!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm pretty sure that textures width and height must be a power of 2 inorder to display propery. Try scaling your bitmap so it's a power of 2.

Comment: Well After lots of effort I figured out you are so right. I didn't give a chance for this power of 2 problem and just because of this I lost 1 day of my life. Now it works perfect.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I'm not a major OpenGL expert either, but from what I see in you code the only thing that's slightly strange is how you load you image, namely this part:

```
bgNightID  = textureStorage.Load(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(),R.drawable.bg_game));
```

What I do is just create a Bitmap instance like so:

```
InputStream is = appContext.getResources().openRawResource(R.drawable.whateverId);
Bitmap bitmap =  = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);
```

And then pass that to GLUtils:

```
GLUtils.texImage2D(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, bitmap , 0);
```

also I never make any call to glTexEnv:

```
//I don't do this:
gl.glTexEnvf(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GL10.GL_TEXTURE_ENV_MODE, GL10.GL_REPLACE);
```

Comment: bgNightID  = textureStorage.Load(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(),R.drawable.bg_game));
Here I'm sending the bitmap to the loader function which does the same thing you do(I shared that function too CODE A) but I'll try your codes anyway maybe I did something wrong.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand your comment. Look, here's a question which shocases (in the question's body itself) the right order in which to call and set the OpenGL state. The code is for JOGl but the openGl calls are the same as on Android: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9500905/opengl-texture-colors-are-wrong. Make sure you're setting everything up in the proper order and that you don't forget anything.

Comment: Oh I think I see the issue. You use glDrawTexfOES. I don't know what that does really (can't find it on the OpenGL docs). Just make a quad, bind the texture and draw the quad, like it's done in the question i linked to in my previous comment.